# OOP design pattern for kmeans clustering

Tags: python-3.x, oop, machine-learning, design-patterns, k-means

I am trying to figure out a appropriate design pattern for my problem.

I have a single data source for many malls that I am querying and then applying preprocessing to convert them into desired features.

Then I am filtering these features for each of the mall and then applying kmeans to each of these malls separately.

I have written my code for a single mall for now by filtering by features for this mall.

I wanted to ask for some direction for a appropriate design pattern to implement my kmeans across all the malls by training my kmeans separately for each mall.

Also should I preprocess all the features for all malls together in a separate Preprocess class or should I do it globally and pass it into my class structures as an input?

Answer (score 0):

Identify what are the core *responsibilities* in your solution. It seems you have:

1. Mall repository (reading mall information from the storage)
2. Mall preprocessor (converts malls to features)
3. Feature filter (filters the features)
4. Clustering (executes a clustering algorithm - e.g. K Means)

The name of the last step should really be related to what real-life problem you're solving and the actual algorithm should be an implementation detail. Since you don't mention this problem in the question it's just "Clustering" for simplicity.

For each of these responsibilities you can create an interface and implementations focused on these responsibilities.

Having such a design it does not matter much if you have a single mall, or multiple malls - you just read them in a for-like loop and process through this pipeline.

I would not think about design patterns here. This usually leads to applying design patterns for the sake of themselves. Try thinking about the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) and most of the rest of the "good stuff" will follow naturally.

If you know some design patterns it's possible that you'll see them emerge while you go. Then you can polish them to match the recommended form of the pattern.